# Multi-booting: Installing multiple Windows 10 OS's alongside multiple Linux OS's

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader

When searching online regarding installing multiple versions of Windows 10. Every site mentions that Windows 10 will have it own "Selection screen" for OS's.

E.g. when you boot your PC, Windows 10A will boot, it will present the choice between Windows 10A and Windows 10B. If you choose 10A, it will just continue booting, if you choose 10B, it will "restart" and boot 10B. AKA the selection screen is actually one of the two versions of Windows.

This is okay-ish for two Windows versions. But I want to install Windows 10 twice alongside Ubuntu twice on one PC. And get to choose which OS I want to boot.

**Tldr;** When installing **Windows 10 twice alongside Ubuntu twice** (4x OS on one PC), is there **a particular order** that I have to follow OR is ther**e a special step for the second Windows 10**?

Comment: The best solution for trying to boot 3 or more operating systems is to use virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 os which Windows does, install by Vista through Windows 11 by creating partitions put linux or Ubuntu last and select something else but not your Windows NTFS Partitions go to make free space put /home but do not format that it will wipe out everything suggest 250000 for the home and then select EFI don't put a figure in leave it blank then click next and you should see a map select state and enter the rest of the details make the password simple you won't be able to reset it once installed. Even I still have issues installing sometimes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is no special order, you just need to partition the drive correctly, it does not matter which order you put the partitions in. The Windows partition should be NTFS, and the Linux parition should be EXT. The Windows boot menu does not support Linux installations, it only let's you pick Windows installations. This means that in order to be able to pick between Linux and Windows you will have to use a different boot menu. You can try to set up the Ubuntu GRUB menu.

If you only install multiple Windows installations on one computer, each installation should automatically be registered as a bootable system and the boot menu should automatically be enabled.

To be able to access the Linux installation files from within Windows, I suggest using [Ext3Fsd](https://github.com/matt-wu/Ext3Fsd). You will have to assign a letter to the Linux partition manually after creating the EXT partition and installing the Ext3Fsd driver. This works really well for me for Android and Linux drives.

To install Windows you have to copy the files from inside the installation ISO file onto a bootable USB device.
For Linux you have to do the same thing using a Linux ISO file and you have to follow the installation, and choose the right partition on the drive so you don't accidentally install the operating systems to the same partition and make sure not to accidentally delete or format the wrong partitions.
There are plenty video's online that go through the installation process of Linux and Windows so if you are unsure you can watch some of those to get an idea of how the installers work and what configurations you should use.

I hope this can help you run multiple operating systems side by side!